# Mediawiki templates - return month number with a zero in front?

Tags: mediawiki

I need a link to a page `2018/02` where `02` is the month number.

I have

```
 {{#expr:{{CURRENTMONTH}}-1}}
```

but this only returns `2`.

I am also using it with a random month (that is not the current one):

```
{{#expr:{{MONTHNUMBER|{{{month|jan}}}}}-1}}
```

where I changed the `MONTHNUMBER` template so that it returns months with a `0` in front, but then the addition/subtraction of the `1` makes it go back to a single digit month number...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `{{padleft:{{#expr:{{MONTHNUMBER|{{{month|jan}}}}}-1}}|2|0}}` and it will always pad whatever string your expression produces with 0s on the left to a length of 2. This should do it.

Comment: Do you know how to get to the previous month in general? Like if I am in January 2018 and I want to link to December 2017?

Comment: Depends what you use. Since you seem to have the ParserFunctions extension installed already (```{{#expr:}}``` is part of it), you could use the ```{{#time:}}``` function and do something like ```{{#time:F Y|January 2018 - 1 month}}```, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for possible output parameters.